# MDX Filter Function with decimal numbers

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to query a cube and filter out dimension based on a measure value equal to decimal. However, when I run the query I can seem to get the decimal value I was expecting. The query I am running is as below.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {
FILTER (
 VISUALTOTALS({ {[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia],[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Canada],[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[France],[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Germany],[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United Kingdom],[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[United States]} })
,[Measures].[Average Sales Amount] >= 61.6484542253521)
 } dimension properties member_type ON ROWS , 
NON EMPTY {{[Measures].[Average Sales Amount]}} 
dimension properties member_type ON COLUMNS FROM [AdventureWorks].
```

The Format_Value and Value are slight different value. Should I be filtering by the format_value instead. Though that does not work either

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? You write "when I run the query I can seem to get the decimal value I was expecting".

Comment: I can see the value I want filter by but when I run the filter with the value nothings gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

It's no need to filter by Format_Value, just use Format_Value when necessary.

Comment: Are you saying i should filter by the value instead. I have tried both values by the way and they are not returning any value even though it exist. However when I try less than I get a value.

Comment: So you mean you get the wrong value. Please try this :Round([Measures].[Average Sales Amount],13) >= 61.6484542253521. It has nothing to do with which value you choose, just about accuracy I think.